# Convert date in string format to date data type

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I would like to convert date in string format ‘mmddyy’ (120618) to date and find the max of date in an Athena table. How can write this sql query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date_parse()` to convert the string into a date:

```sql
select date_parse('120618', '%c%d%y')
```

Therefore, you could use it like this:

```sql
SELECT
  MAX(date_parse(date_field, '%c%d%y')) as dt
FROM table
```

See: [Date and Time Functions and Operators — Presto Documentation](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html)

By the way, you should tell whoever made that original data format that it is a poor way to store dates. ISO format is better (eg `2018-12-06`).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just output your date by using the ORDER BY , plus ASC | DESC (depends on what you mean by "max of date"), command and just use the first output you get? By using LIMIT?

Comment: The date is in string format. I’m trying to do select max(order_date) from table. But since order_date is in string format , the maximum value is not returned